# What is best technique for switching Xaml views?

Tags: xaml, caliburn.micro

I have "alternative" xaml views for a viewmodel and I am currently using a technique where I set the style property on the view (containing a control template) and would like to know what is the best/preferred Caliburn technique to re-invoke conventions, bindings, etc., that are setup initially by Caliburn when showing the viewmodel.

I am using a View-Model-First approach, so possibly I am using the wrong technique and should be looking at a way (e.g. View contexts) to have the Viewmodel instigate the change?

Thanks

Comment: +1, just hope it doesn't fall under being opinion based response so I hope an answer explains *why* it's the best technique

Comment: Maybe I should qualify the question as "good technique" instead of "best technique" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<ContentControl cm:View.Context="{Binding CurrentView, Mode=TwoWay}" cm:View.Model="{Binding}" />`

Multiple views over 1 viewmodel technique.  Then the folder structure would be slightly different to help organize but namespace is how view is found to place into the contentcontrol content.  I use this in multiple projects

Viewmodel logic facilitates the view "switching".

Comment: The default is to name them `[PathToViews]\NameView.xaml` and `[PathToViews]\Name\ContextName.xaml` however it is very simple to change this if you wanted to use NameView.Context.xaml or something

Comment: Ok, I found that the old Silverlight "HelloScreens" sample demonstrates this.