# How to organize ViewModel and View projects to use View.Context switching?

Tags: xaml, caliburn.micro

I have my views and viewmodels in separate projects, and I use ViewLocator.AddNamespaceMapping() calls to map everything.

How do I continue to keep things separate and use the View.Context switching recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390698/what-is-best-technique-for-switching-xaml-views) ?

Assume I have my viewmodel project with top level functional folders:

MyViewModels/
            ---/FormDesigner/FormDesignerViewModel.cs
            ---/GroupDesigner/GroupDesignerViewModel.cs
            ---/FilterDesigner/FilterDesignerViewModel.cs
            etc.

And my view project like:

MyViews/
            ---/FormDesigner/FormDesignerView.xaml
            ---/GroupDesigner/GroupDesignerView.xaml
            ---/FilterDesigner/FilterDesignerView.xaml

And I currently map in my Bootstrapper like:

ViewLocator.AddNamespaceMapping("MyViewModels", "MyViews);

How would I introduce View.Context switching for alternate views for each of my current Xaml views? Thanks

Comment: For example, just assume two separate contexts for each view, e.g. Master and Detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the built in conventions will take care of it for you (you could also specify additional conventions), provided your views are namespaced/named correctly ([See "Multiple Views over the Same ViewModel")](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens%2c%20Conductors%20and%20Composition&referringTitle=Documentation).

Usually, you would place your views (if you wanted switching) in a structure like:

```
Folder:    Views/FormDesigner/         // Folder Structure not critical
NameSpace: YourApp.Views.FormDesigner
XAML:      YourApp.Views.FormDesigner.Master.Xaml
XAML:      YourApp.Views.FormDesigner.Detail.Xaml
Binding:   <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding Path=ActiveItem}" 
               cal:View.Context="Master" />
```

Your binding may vary, and for switching, you'll want to bind the `Context` to a property on the ViewModel (which indicates either `Master`, or `Detail` in your situation.

You can use your existing view, but you'll have to change the name from `FormDesignerView.xaml` if you want to switch the context.

I had a crack at explaining the built in `Caliburn.Micro` conventions governing that behaviour in this answer: [One ViewModel, multiple views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788671/one-viewmodel-multiple-views/18818113#18818113)

Comment: You were correct. I didn't have to change anything to get this to work. I actually took the old Silverlight CM sample called "HelloScreens" and broke up like:   

- Caliburn.Micro.HelloScreens  
- Caliburn.Micro.HelloScreens.Framework  
- Caliburn.Micro.HelloScreens.ViewModels   
- Caliburn.Micro.HelloScreens.Views  

Basically moving all viewmodels to the ViewModels project including the ShellViewModel, and moving all "framework" stuff to the Framework project, including IShell, etc. I had to add the override to the bootstrapper:

Comment: Good stuff, glad it helped =D